# What is the difference between `Vertex Centric Indices` query and a simple `has()`

Tags: titan

What is the difference between `Vertex Centric Indices` query and a simple `has()` query.

I have a vertex having property like targetGender(male,female), isAvailable(yes,no), materialType(glass,plastic,..)

now I should be able to query using all these property.Which one is efficient query:

```
`g.query().has("materialType",glass);`
```

or

```
v.query().direction(Direction.IN)
                   .labels(edgeLabel.toString()).has("materialType", glass);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a "difference" in that they aren't comparable things, so much as they are  related things.  If you don't define a vertex centric index, and issue a `has` based query where you hit some vertices with several hundred thousand edges, you will get an answer, but you will iterate all edges to do it.  If you do the same `has` query and have vertex centric indices defined, then Titan will make use of those indices to filter those edges saving a lot of time on the query.

No matter what you choose to do, `has` will work - vertex centric indices will just make it more efficient.

Comment: but if you do `has` on a index property then it will not iterate over all vertices. so in that case i dont think its different from vertex centic query as `has` is avoiding uneccessary vertex travel.In many case you cant just perform vertex centric query as you u have to combine multiple property

Comment: If you do a `has` and don't have a vertex centric index, Titan will read all of the edges and filter them in-memory.  If you do a `has` and have a vertex centric index, Titan will know how to skip the ones you don't want and not load them into memory at all.  Those things are hidden from you behind the `has`.